# How to group numpy array position values?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

There is a np.array:

```
[
array(['x_0', '2/20/1990', '3/20/1990'], dtype=object), 
array(['x_1', '1', '2'], dtype=object), 
array(['x_3', 'foo', 'bar'], dtype=object), etc...]
```

I want to make an array that will contain all of this values grouped (all first values  with 1-st values, second values with second, and separated with "\n":

like this:

```
[array(['x_0\nx_1\nx_n, '2/20/1990\n1\nfoo', '3/20/1990\n2\bar', etc], dtype=object)]
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use python built-in [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#zip) function and `join` :

```
>>> a=[
... np.array(['x_0', '2/20/1990', '3/20/1990'], dtype=object), 
... np.array(['x_1', '1', '2'], dtype=object), 
... np.array(['x_3', 'foo', 'bar'], dtype=object)]

>>> new=np.array(['\n'.join(k) for k in zip(*a)],dtype=object)
>>> new
array(['x_0\nx_1\nx_3', '2/20/1990\n1\nfoo', '3/20/1990\n2\nbar'], dtype=object)
```

Answer (score 1):

First transpose your matrix, and then concatenate values of each row using '\n' as a separator.

```
map(lambda x: '\n'.join(x), a.T)
```